# mysql inserting data to another

Tags: php, mysql

I have following mysql db table structure:

**Table_1**:

[image]

I need to insert the values (post_id and its corresponding `geo_lat` and `geo_lon` into another table as below)

**Table_2**:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table_2(post_id,geo_lat,geo_lon)
          SELECT post_id,meta_key IN(geo_lat),meta_key IN(geo_lon) //????
          FROM table_1";
$wpdb->query($query);
```

Of course it is wrong and I am bit stuck to how to do it (pretty new to php).

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `GROUP BY` and `MAX` together to "rotate" these values:

```
INSERT INTO table_2 (Post_id, Geo_lat, Geo_lon)
     SELECT post_id,
            MAX(IF(meta_key='geo_lat',meta_value,NULL)),          
            MAX(IF(meta_key='geo_lon',meta_value,NULL))
       FROM table_1
   GROUP BY post_id
```

It is  kind of self-explanatory,  but if  you want to  understand better
what  this  query  does  you  can experiment  with  a  simpler  `SELECT`
statement:

```
SELECT post_id,
       IF(meta_key='geo_lat',meta_value,NULL) lat,
       IF(meta_key='geo_lon',meta_value,NULL) lon
  FROM table_1
```

What this does is to return a  three column set, first is the ID, second
column (named `lat` here) will bring the `meta_value` only if `meta_key`
in the row is `geo_lat`, otherwise `NULL`. Third column is the same, but
for `geo_lon`. It will generate a set like:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| post_id | lat     | lon     |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 1       | 12.400  | NULL    |
| 1       | NULL    | 123.000 |
| 2       | 234.200 | NULL    |
| 2       | NULL    | 4.200   |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Then, with the use of `GROUP_BY` rows will be grouped when the ID is the
same, and the values  used on `lat` and `lon` will  be decided by `MAX`.
Since `NULL` is always "smaller",  only non-null values will be selected
effectifelly joining the rows into:

```
  SELECT post_id,
         MAX(IF(meta_key='geo_lat',meta_value,NULL)) lat,
         MAX(IF(meta_key='geo_lon',meta_value,NULL)) lon
    FROM table_1
GROUP BY post_id
```

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| post_id | lat     | lon     |
+---------+---------+---------+
| 1       | 12.400  | 123.000 |
| 2       | 234.200 | 4.200   |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: This is pretty cool! Thank you very much! Much appreciate it! :)

Comment: Thanks, happy to help :-)